# How to recover from NoReplicaOnlineException with one Kafka broker?

Tags: message-queue, apache-kafka

We have a really simple Kafka **0.8.1.1** set up in our development lab. It's just one node. Periodically, we run into this error:

```
[2015-08-10 13:45:52,405] ERROR Controller 0 epoch 488 initiated state change for partition [test-data,1] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [test-data,1] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]
        at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:61)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:336)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:185)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:99)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:96)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:743)
```

Can anyone recommend a strategy for recovering from this? Is there such a thing or do we need to build out another node or two and set up the replication factor on our topics to cover all of the nodes that we put into the cluster?

We have 3 zookeeper nodes that respond very well for other applications like Storm and HBase, so we're pretty confident that ZooKeeper isn't to blame here. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "recover from NROE"? Is the broker running fine after the exception?

Comment: The weird part is that the broker appears to be running just fine. We see no errors in server.log, but all of our topics throw that error in state-change.log. Restarting the service didn't help. I also increased the ZK timeouts to pretty ridiculous lengths and that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: Please let me know if you find a solution to this. I'm facing the same issue periodically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is about Kafka 0.8 which should be out of support if I am not mistaken. However, for future readers the following guidelines should be relevant:

1. If you care about stability, uptime, reliability or anything in this general direction, make sure you have at least 3 kafka Nodes.
2. If you have a problem in an old kafka version, seriously consider upgrading to the latest kafka version. At time of writing we are already at Kafka 2